# How to create a List of values aggregation after a join on DataFrame elements?

Tags: scala, join, apache-spark, dataframe

Instead of a matematical aggregation using join by key and the sum, an average, max, like:

```
df.join(dfCopy, df("key") === dfCopy("key"))).agg(sum(df("value")))
```

I need to do:

```
df.join(dfCopy, df("key") === dfCopy("key"))).agg(List(df("value"))) //Basically adding to a list all the values that match in a join
```

To reitirate, add all the joined valued in the "value" column in a List.

What is the best way to do this using DataFrame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.collect_list

df.join(dfCopy, df("key") == dfCopy("key")).agg(collect_list(df("value")))
```

See: http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$

Note: collect_list is only available as of 1.6.0 and I believe it expects you to be using a HiveContext, instead of a SQLContext.

Comment: I have up voted your answer @Hamel, I will tick it as correct answer as soon as I test it. Can you do the same to the question please? Someone has downvoted it not sure why!